# How I do convert a Julia stream to "byte content" for a Python package?

Tags: python, io, stream, julia

I maintain [OdsIo.jl](https://github.com/sylvaticus/OdsIO.jl), a Julia package that wraps, for ods files specifically, [ezodf](https://pythonhosted.org/ezodf/), a Python package for various OpenDocument formats,

My "ods_readall" function starts by calling `ezodf.opendoc`.

`ezodf.opendoc` supports as input, other than the filename, the file byte content itself:

```
ezodf.opendoc(filename)¶
    Parameters: filename (str) – a filename or the file-content as bytes
```

Is there a way I can use it with a Julia stream (e.g. a network gzipped file as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557706/how-do-i-read-a-gzipped-xlsx-file-in-julia) ) intead of plain files?

Comment: `bytes = read("myfile.odt")` gives you the file as an array of bytes (unsigned 8-bit chars) in Julia, which should be passable to Python as bytes as long as you know what the Python package expects. You could get the bytes from a Julia IO stream with `bytes = read(iostream)` as well,

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, at least for HTTP, that is what I was interested to:

```
using HTTP, Pipe, PyCall

const  pyio  = PyNULL()
const  ezodf = PyNULL()

copy!(pyio, pyimport("io"))
copy!(ezodf, pyimport("ezodf"))

function readstream(istream)
    return ezodf.opendoc(pyio.BytesIO(istream))
end

urlData = "https://github.com/sylvaticus/OdsIO.jl/raw/master/test/spreadsheet.ods"

doc = @pipe HTTP.get(urlData).body |> readstream(_)
```